# Is there way to disable the status line for certain windows?

Tags: vim

A buffer plugin I use creates a separate window with a list of buffers. This unnecessarily has its own status line which takes up space. Is there a way to disable the statusline for certain buffers/windows?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to switch status line visibility
selectively for certain windows. The only related feature is
controlled by the `laststatus` option that defines when to display
the status line of the last window.

You might be interested in the [buftabs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1664) plugin that shows a list
of buffers in the status line saving vertical screen space for editing.

Comment: Why does the help say "global or local to window"?

Comment: @Owen Typo in older vim? `:h 'laststatus'` says it is global only (vim-7.3.266).

Comment: @Owen:  `statusline` is global or local to window, but `laststatus` is global only.

Answer (score 2):

Try to emulate absence of statusline instead:

```
let &l:statusline='%{getline(line("w$")+1)}'
```

. It is also almost possible to put correct highlighting there, but implementation should be slow.

Comment: I thought about this emulation, but it is far from ideal.  It is more like a raw preview of a line (for example, even tab indentation, shown as `^I`, requires manual handling).

Comment: And by the way, I think the line number should be `line("w0")-1`, as typical minibufexpl-like plugin opens its window on the top with rather useless status line content.  But it becomes more complicated because of possible vertical splits below that window.

Comment: @ib statusline is always at the bottom. I don't think it is a good idea to get line from the lower buffer in the upper window's statusline: I guess this will need some hacks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can write a small function and put it in autocommands, which will disable and enable laststatus option depending of current buffer name.
Something like that:

```
au BufEnter,BufWinEnter,WinEnter,CmdwinEnter *
                       \ call s:disable_statusline('buffer name')
fun! s:disable_statusline(bn)
   if a:bn == bufname('%')
       set laststatus=1
   else
       set laststatus=2
   endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score -1):

You could set it locally:

```
setlocal statusline=
```

Comment: That doesn't remove it, it just sets it back to default.